# How to interpret the probabilities in competing risks analysis?

Tags: survival, competing-risks

I am using the cmprsk and timereg packages in R to conduct competing risks data. the data is confidential so I cannot share, but I will point to the tutorial I am basing this work on http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/12763_bd046f2a52e444599992161c91dc2904.html

I would like to know how to interpret each line (say in the 7th graph down) of the probability of each event occuring. Do all probabilities by the end of the study window require to equal 100%? It seems to me that when calculating probabilities across certain groups, all probabiltities must be added to equal 100% (or 1).